# SQL regex extract similar pattern text

Tags: sql, string, amazon-redshift

I am using SQL in redshift. So here is what I have:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| text | [{"name":"alex","country":"france","name":"mike","country":"usa","name":"Jake", "country":"italy"}] |

I would like to extract all the names from the text into one column:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | alex,mike,jake |

Comment: Jake has Italy in this dict

Comment: @gajendragarg  Yeah it should be similar to what Alex's and Mike's.. basically I want their names

Comment: Did you try any regex?

Comment: @gajendragarg I did regex_count and it shows there are three names, but I can't figure out how to list the names.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this regex `(?:"name":")\w+`

Comment: Here is what I get when I run it:

Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>>="name":")'.
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>>="name":")'.
  code:      8002
  context:   setup_regex_init
  query:     114207327

Comment: I give you a snip of code as example how it will be used, you can deal with is?

Comment: Doesnt work in redshift SQL.. I am not using python, just sql query

Comment: I didn't use `redshift` before, can you give example how apply any regex in it?

Comment: https://hevodata.com/learn/amazon-redshift-regex/#replace

Comment: Hmm sorry, still not able to figure it out 

Comment: I changed the answer try it,  I'm the one should be sorry I didn't notice the label `amazon-redsgift` in your question, so i can't help you, sorry

Comment: Redshift has json functions, inherited from postgres.
However postgres ones were not designed to handle duplicate keys.

Redshift also has regex functions, inherited from postgres. Search for regex_replace in aws.
First stab at your solution: 
- replace all "name": with empty string.
- replace all "[^"]*":"[^"]*", with empty string.
- you now have a comma-sep list of "somename"... crossjoin it if you need one name per row.